# string.rstrip() is removing extra characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Why does this statement remove the `'E'` in `'PIPELINE'`:

```
In: 'PIPELINE_DEV'.rstrip('_DEV')
Out: 'PIPELIN'
```

But this statement does not remove the `'S'`:

```
In: 'PIPELINES_DEV'.rstrip('_DEV')
Out: 'PIPELINES'
```

This statement removes all of the E's at the end:

```
In: 'PIPELINEEEEEEEE_DEV'.rstrip('_DEV')
Out: 'PIPELIN'
```

When I turn the rstrip into 2 separate statements, it works fine:

```
In: 'PIPELINE_DEV'.rstrip('DEV').rstrip('_')
Out: 'PIPELINE'
```

Comment: Why would you expect `'PIPELINES_DEV'.rstrip('_DEV')` to remove the `S`?

Comment: A multi-character string passed to `.strip()` or `.rstrip()` represents a *set of characters to be removed* (in any order), NOT a literal string.

Comment: @ZachGates I would not expect `'PIPELINES_DEV'.rstrip('_DEV')` to remove the `S`. At the time of this question, I did not understand why it was removing the `E` in `PIPELINE` but not the `S` in `PIPELINES`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`rstrip` removes any trailing instances of the characters you supply from the string you apply it on until it finds something that doesn't match. This is stated in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

> The chars argument *is not a suffix*; rather, *all combinations of its values are stripped*

Using `rstrip('_DEV')` it will remove `_DEV` from the string and then all `E`s (or `'D'`s or `'V'`s or `'_'`s) since those fall in the character set you've given (and no other character that isn't in that set has been found).

When you use `.rstrip('DEV').rstrip('_')` the first call to `rstrip` strips off `'DEV'` and then stops because `'_'` isn't in the character set `'DEV'`. `'_'` is then removed when the second call to `rstrip` is made.

---

Note that in Python >= 3.9, [`str.removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) was [added](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) in order to address this common misconception. Using `removesuffix`, you can supply a suffix string that is removed, if present, as a suffix of the string it is applied on.

Your example:

```
'PIPELINE_DEV'.removesuffix('_DEV')
```

would only remove the `'_DEV'` suffix.

Comment: Your 'note' is exactly the answer to the problem here. To help future visitors without this *exact* issue you could mention that `str.removeprefix` also exists:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix